# Azure Docker Web App - Failed to update data for container settings

Tags: linux, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to configure continuous deployment for my Web App in Azure so it deploys every time I push an updated container image to the Azure registry.

However, when I go to "Container Settings" and set "Continuous Deployment" to true and then hit save I get the following error:

"Failed to update data for container settings."

I'm not sure how to start debugging this error message to find out what the issue is.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can set up continuous integration/deployment for Azure Container Registry. For private registries, you can refresh the container by stopping and then starting your web app. Or you can change or add a dummy application setting to force a refresh of your container. Ensure that the configuration settings are correct and then re-try.

Comment: This just worked after revisiting the portal after a couple of days. Must have needed a bit of bedding in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just worked after revisiting the portal after a couple of days. Must have needed a bit of bedding in...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error message when trying to update the configuration of a multi-container app.

The Azure portal sends the update as a request to their management API and the JSON response to this request contains a more detailed error message. This might help with debugging. For example, in my case the configuration was too long and this was kind of communicated in the response that I was able to find through the network tab of my browsers developer tools.

Comment: Can you and how do you check the detailed error message from the Azure portal?